# Operations Manager (SCOM) 2012 Agentless monitoring in DMZ

Tags: scom

I've run into a new scenario recently.  We have a couple terminal servers in our DMZ that have SCCM or SCSM consoles installed, so we can't install SCOM agents on them.  Instead, I have to monitor them agentlessly.  However, they are in the DMZ so my SCOM management servers can't access them to add them to agentless monitoring.  Does anyone know of a way to add them so I can monitor them?  I have other servers in the DMZ that can do the monitoring.  I just need to figure out how to get them into SCOM and assign proxy agents to monitor them.

I'm a bit lost and standard web searches turn nothing up.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the machines in the DMZ that do have the agent to monitor the agentless machines.  You do this via the agent discovery and choosing an existing agent as the proxy.

Here is a reference on adding agentless machine. Note not all management pack features work with agentless monitoring.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh264859.aspx